# How to modify Solr files from Drupal UI?

Tags: 7, search

I'm looking for a module that allow you to manipulated Solr files  (synonyms.txt, stopwords.txt, spellings.txt, solrconfig.xml, protwords.txt) content without actually modify those file  from Drupal.

Why ? I'm currently Pantheon which support Solr; however, `solrconfig.xml` and `synonyms.txt` cannot be modified and I would like to alters that content but with a module.

Comment: How would you manipulate a file without modifying it?

Comment: I guess that is very unclear.  My problem is that I don't have access to those files. So I need to modify on a module level. This makes more sense ?

Comment: Nope :) If Pantheon don't let you alter those files, you can't alter them. They live on the server well outside of your user's privileges; Drupal can't tell the solr server which config files to use. You can use the pantheon solr module to post schema files from one of the normal solr modules' folder, but it'll only post the files that are allowed